# ScriptResource.axd 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have this WebApp in .NET 3.5, using MS Ajax and jQuery UI. It works fine locally but when I publish it on the statging server it gives a 'Sys' undefined javaScript error. Furhter investigation, I found that the .axd files are not loaded and it is a 404.
I checked the web.confing and I have the necessary entries under the .
I googled and read every post and could not find a solution for it. 
Is there anyone who has run in to a prblme like this before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just ran into it with our server on IIS 6. It was handled by making sure to have in the system.web section (different for IIS7).

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Well it turned out that there was a URLRewriter installed for PHP and that was intercepting the calls. So we removed it and then things worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I also saw this behavior on a hosted web service; the local version had no problem.   After trying dozens of variation of system.web/httpHandlers and system.webServer/handlers statements, I finally gave up and tried the most inelegant solution of creating a dummy ScriptResource.axd - voila, it worked!    I'm guessing there was some hidden validation setting in IIS at the hosting level despite setting 'validate=false' in web.config.

Comment: 2020 and your solution works for me.
Indeed I have the same code coexisting as a independent web site and also as application within on another web.

Answer (score 2):

I had correct settings in web.config, I fixed the issue by changing the IIS 8 to run in 'Classic' mode rather than 'Integrated' mode.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using Routing in Web Forms Application. Following steps resolved the issue for me. Its weird but it worked. It might help someone who has implemented routing in web forms. **My project was .Net 4.5**

1. I commented    `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`
2. Built the Project
3. Uncommented :  `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`
4. Built the Project
5. Loaded page again and Web page animation for Update Panel was working fine

Comment: I had same issue. Could not figure it out so I left ajaxcontroltoolkit alone for a long time. I came back to use a combobox and saw all those 404 errors. I removed the routing rewrite code in my web.config which was implemented to remove the .aspx from the url bar and it worked.

Comment: Tanks, this solution helped me. but there is a explanation. If you uncommented Register route and your code works fin this is beacuse of SourceResource  loaded from cache. if you uncommented routeconfig the probblem is came back.
I used this solution by adding my mvc codes into an area

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Add the below handler to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this same issue after migrating to SmarterASP.Net.

Fixed it by creating empty file ScriptResource.axd