# ASP.NET web application working on test server but not on production server

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5, production-environment

I have an application that we've recently converted from a Web Site to a Web Application, and migrated to a more modern server.

After some rigorous testing on what I'll refer to as our "test box", we launched the new version of the application, but we've had some strange errors, some of which are causing real trouble for our users.

When I press a button that previously performed some action, it now causes a 404 error (viewed using Chrome dev tools), to the path ScriptResource.axd?d=aaabbbbccc[*snip*].

The functionality works fine on the testing box, and the web.config files are identical on both boxes. ASP.NET, MVC etc. are all installed on the production box, as on the test box. The production box and test box are both running IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the other similar questions on Stackoverflow?

[ScriptResource.axd 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798020/scriptresource-axd-404-not-found)

[scriptresource.axd 404 error in asp net 4 application - webresource works fine though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797435/scriptresource-axd-404-error-in-asp-net-4-application-webresource-works-fine-t)

[.axd files generate a 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098548/axd-files-generate-a-404-error)

[When I browse http://localhost:8004/elmah.axd, it generates 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015013/when-i-browse-http-localhost8004-elmah-axd-it-generates-404-error)